# Wood plank falling off fence

Tags: wood, tools, fence

A wooden plank on my fence is sagging. It's stuck so it's very hard to push it back up. How do I put it back in place **and** what tool should I use?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would use a tool called a "superbar" (sometimes called a pry bar). It looks like a crowbar, but is smaller and flatter

[image]

Place some wood on the pry part and use it to help push the board back into place.

Comment: Might be worth adding to add some construction adhesive between the two boards prior to prying it back into place, then toe-screwing it together (even if temporary until the adhesive dries).

Comment: Or wonder bar, I would use a 2x4 and fulcrum , after it is in place it will need toe nailing or it will slip again.